# Android out of memory error on version greater than 4.0

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am creating bitmap drawable at run time and making them as a background for my views in activity `onResume()` event and I am removing background images `onStop()` event , to remove bitmap references so that bitmaps can be recycled.The application works fine for android version 2.3.5 but it throws exception on android version 4.1.2 . What could possibly be the reason? . I have also used softReferences from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html.
I am getting following exception. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    10-11 14:54:48.812: E/dalvikvm-heap(1760): Out of memory on a 41508-byte allocation.
    10-11 14:54:48.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-11 14:54:48.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1760): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    10-11 14:54:48.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    10-11 14:54:48.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
    10-11 14:54:48.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1760):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:301)
```

Answer (score 1):

while selecting file convert it to bitmap using following function and work with result,,

```
public static Bitmap convertToBitmap(File f) 
    {


         try {
                //Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                //The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=250;

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale=1;
                while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale*=2;

                //Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }
        return bmp;
    }//convertToBitmap
```

Comment: I don't want to compromise on quality of image.

Comment: then if u wont compromise quality then add memory ti ur device,,,that's why it gives u out of memory exception,,,even if u compromise it wont look different from original file